# White status bar on iPhone X on PWA

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, progressive-web-apps, iphone-x

Our team use PWA for our website and I have an issue with status bar color on iPhone X.
Here is my index.html meta tags:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="transparent">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0,  viewport-fit=cover">`

Changing status bar content doesn't help:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

I was looking for solution but I haven't found it yet. For comparing I've attached two screens from Xcode simulators with iPhone X and iPhone XS based on iOS 12.1:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB5ji.png

on iPhone XS it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Since `black-translucent` fills the status bar area with the background-color of the app's body tag, like padding, I'd play around with the size, background-color and position of they body element.